# Javascript generator function yield is not assigning value in variable

Tags: javascript

I am facing a issue while using yield in javascript generator.Let's have a look of my code first-

```js
function* gen(a, b) {
  let k = yield a + b;
  let m = yield a + b + k;
  yield a + b + k + m;
}

let x = gen(10, 20);

console.log(x.next());
console.log(x.next());
console.log(x.next());
```

In the above code,at the first time when I run next(),it gave me a value of 30.But when I tried  second time,in the second next(),it gave me a NAN value.It means,yield didn't assign the value of a+b in k.Instead it derectly move to the next line.But I think,it should assign value to k first.

What is happening here?Please let me know if you know.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a generator, the expression:

```
yield <someExpression>
```

evaluates to the value *passed into* the generator with `.next`, like this:

```js
function* gen(a, b) {
  const valPassedIn = yield 'foo';
  console.log('valPassedIn', valPassedIn);
}

let x = gen(10, 20);

const containsFoo = x.next();
x.next(123);
```

In your code, since you aren't calling `.next` with anything, both `k` and `m` are `undefined`, so they can't be `+`d with anything (they'll produce NaN).

For what it sounds like you want, calculate the sum, yield it, and assign it to `k` separately.

```js
function* gen(a, b) {
  let k = a + b;
  yield k;
  let m = a + b + k;
  yield m;
  yield a + b + k + m;
}

let x = gen(10, 20);

console.log(x.next());
console.log(x.next());
console.log(x.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

`k` and `m` remain undefined as the assignment to them is *after* the `yield` has completed. Assign value to the respective variables *before* the `yield`

```js
function* gen(a, b) {
  k = a + b;
  yield k;
  m = a + b + k
  yield m;
  yield a + b + k + m;
}

let x = gen(10, 20);
console.log(x.next());
console.log(x.next());
console.log(x.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `k` is `undefined` the first time we run `next()`